# A "strong" iterator pointer/reference

Tags: c++

Is there such thing as a "strong" iterator. What I mean is an iterator that sticks to the value it is referencing rather than the address it is in, such that if the value gets swapped to a different address, the iterator will continue pointing to it in this new address; regardless of where it gets moved to in the data structure?

Comment: yes, it's possible, but that needs support in the data structure itself with extra overhead (so you cannot do this with the regular implementations of the STL containers)

Comment: Unfortunately, no, not in the STL. This would be a nice feature at times. It would even be convenient to only have "weak" iterators, i.e. an iterator that can safely be tested for expiration.

Comment: @KarolyHorvarh I guess you wanted to say "C++ Standard Library Containers", right?

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek: bloody terminology.. I saw that topic. honestly, it would be easier to reuse that name for the same thing...

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a way to implement one that would work with the Standard Library nicely? 
I'm trying to think of an efficient way, but would enjoy other input.

Comment: I'm thinking this may actually be possible without any container support. One could write a general purpose "strong_iterator" class whose constructor takes an arbitrary iterator as an rvalue reference and in essence construct the iterator by moving another iterator: strong_iterator(vectr.begin()) you can then overload copy assignment or construction operators in the strong_iterator to perform a "sticky" copy where it moves itself to the new iterator or something of the likes. Before attempting to implement this, however, I would appreciate other inputs on possible caveats I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. But why? And what would you want `std::iter_swap(strong_a, strong_b);` to do?

As Karoly Horvath points out, you could implement your own container that has its own iterators (Iterator is just a concept, not any one type).

As for a way to "implement one that would work with the Standard Library nicely", it depends what part of the standard library you have in mind. You can't go adding things to the containers (unless you can figure out a way to implement what you want with Allocators or something). But if you created your own somehow, you you'd have some level of compatibility with the standard algorithms.

Finally, you could probably implement something like this with a special wrapper class, that would let you do something like `std::vector<strong_pointable<int>>` where `strong_pointable<int>` would generally act like int but let provide a way to get a special "strong pointer" or whatever you want to call it that would keep track of things as they get move-constructed.

But this is an odd thing to ask for. I suspect you are Doing It Wrong if you want this functionality.

Comment: Ben, in the case of `std::iter_swap(strong_a, strong_b)`, optimally you wouldn't do anything, but underneath you could do what a `strong reference` would do, just swap their positions in the list, but maintain the iterators pointing to the data's new position in the list.

In terms of implementation, would there be anything wrong with the implementation I suggested in the comments above? I think you can do this and still be fully compatible with the Standard Library without needing to go deep into allocators.

Comment: Also, why would you suspect I am doing something wrong? This is rather common behavior, one such example is quicksort. Quicksort swaps around elements with the pivot constantly in its partitioning step, but it needs to know where the pivot is at all times so it needs to keep updating the position of the pivot between calls. It would simplify this and other scenarios greatly to have a structure that kept track for itself, freeing the user from this menial task.

Comment: I think you may be doing it wrong in that I've never heard of something quite like this, and your question isn't specific about what part of the standard library you want it to work with. I can't see a way to do this without a significant performance hit wherein each assignment requires checking the heap for these strong iterators.

You can get a lot of what I think you want by working with containers of pointers to heap-allocated objects. Then you can keep pointers to objects and even if the pointers in the containers get reordered, you still have a pointer to the object.

Comment: Can you give a concrete usage example for what you want to do?

Comment: You're absolutely right about the pointer arithmetic; it is something which isn't really doable with iterators, so any code you want to write that would take advantage of pointers in that way would be more lengthy to write with iterators. However, I digress, as it's become very clear over a span of a couple of questions I have asked that this behavior can't be implemented in an easy Standard Library-compliant way, so don't worry about it :)