# Inject a specific move-constructor onto an arbitrary type based on a specific type

Tags: c++, templates

I have a feeling I'm going to get burned at the stake for asking this question, however my C++ knowledge is limited, and I am learning.

Is there a way to hide/override another type `T`'s move behavior when targetting instances of `my_class` similar to what is done with other operators?

For example:

```
template<typename T>
class my_class
{
...
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, my_class& c);
```

But instead, with move assignment/move constructors.

If I wanted to override the behavior for move (construction or assignment) for types `T` when dealing with instances of `my_class`, is this possible? Does this require some kind of reflection or can it be performed with constructs such as `friend` or simply declaring a function at global scope with both types as parameters?

Example assuming `T` is some type, I would like to hide/override `T`'s behavior for move construction and assignment:

```
T t;
t = my_class<T>(...); // move-assign T from my_class rvalue
T t(my_class<T>(...)); // move-construct T from my_class rvalue
```

I'm assuming somebody is also going to ask why in the world I would want to do something like this, and [the answer to that question lies in my comments here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939340/a-strong-iterator-pointer-reference/29969404#29969404)

Comment: `T t = my_class<T>(...);` and `T t(my_class<T>(...));` both do the same thing, and neither of them makes any sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Barry Read the question all the way to the end ;)
Kind of, one calls the move assignment operator for T and the other the move constructor. I want to change this behavior for classes that try to move `my_class`.

Comment: There is no reflection in C++ so that won't work.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera How about you put your question *in your question*?

Comment: @Barry the question is in the question. It's all up there, I don't see what the mystery is.
I edited the question to try and be clearer.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera *"one calls the move assignment operator for T and the other the move constructor."*  That is not correct.  As Barry commented, both do the same thing.

Comment: @DrewDormann irrelevant to the question, but ok, I changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're trying to inject a specific move-constructor onto an arbitrary type based on your specific type. There are languages that let you do that, but C++ is thankfully not one of them.

Nothing is stopping you from introducing your *own* type though. You can wrap an arbitrary `T` and "inject" your move-constructor there:

```
template <typename T>
struct wrapped
{
    wrapped(my_class<T>&& cls) {
        // move-construct val as you wish
    }

    wrapped& operator=(my_class<T>&& cls) {
        // move-assign val as you wish
    }

    // possibly other constructors? 

    T val;
};

wrapped<T> t(my_class<T>(...)); // uses your move constructor
```

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, for my scenario, I was just trying to implement a different type of iterator that played nicely with the Standard Library, and if I have to write a "wrapped" container for every container in the Standard Library to do so then it's really not worth it.

Comment: And you're sure that you can't do this with move? Because you can overload other operators for arbitrary types, most common of which is the shift operators. So it's not as "weird" as you and others made it out to be.
`std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, SomeClass& obj);` granted the member class has to denote them as "friend".

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera Yes, I'm sure. Why don't you have `my_class<T>` just create a `T`?

Comment: The whole premise of the question revolved around making a container-agnostic iterator with [special behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939340/a-strong-iterator-pointer-reference/29969404#29969404), however, the behavior requires other classes to treat the class differently. I tried thinking of a bottom up solution starting from the iterator class itself, but the problem really requires a top-down solution where containers treat this kind of iterator differently.